# Simplest transformation from XOR to CNF SAT

Tags: satisfiability

What is the simplest way to transfrom $a\newcommand*\xor{\oplus}b=c$ to a CNF SAT expression with minimum number of clauses. The default transformation requires upto 9 clauses. I think we can do much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with transforming $a\oplus b = True$. This is simple enough, since it happens if and only if either one of $a$ or $b$ is $True$ and the other is $False$. We can easily encode it as follows:

$$(a\lor b)\land (\lnot a \lor \lnot b)$$

Now, to transform $a\oplus b = c$ we need two cases: one for when $c=True$ and the other for when $c=False$. We covered already the case for $c=True$, so now lets go through $c=False$. In this case, both $a$ and $b$ must be the same value. Notice that $\lnot a \lor b$ is equivalent to $a\rightarrow b$, and hence $(\lnot a \lor b) \land (\lnot b \lor a)$ is equivalent to $(a\rightarrow b)\land (b \rightarrow a)$ which is also equivalent to $a\longleftrightarrow b$. Hence, when $c=False$ we need the encoding to be:

$$(\lnot a \lor b) \land (a \lor \lnot b)$$

Combining the two is rather easy:

$$(a\lor b\lor \lnot c)\land (\lnot a\lor \lnot b\lor \lnot c) \land (\lnot a \lor b\lor c) \land (a \lor\lnot b\lor c)$$

I will leave it to you to prove that this is indeed equivalent to $a\oplus b = c$

:)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer a more straightforward method for transforming XOR equations into SAT.

**step 1:**

Regardless of the number of variables on the right side of the equality, we can shift them to the left by iteratively XOR-ing the same variables one by one. For example:

$$a \oplus b = c \iff a \oplus b \oplus c = 0$$

**step 2:**

Now, **this equation implies that the count of 1s in $a , b , c$ must be even.** We can express all the clauses for cases where the count of 1s is odd, corresponding to an odd number of negations:

$$(a \lor b \lor \neg c) \land (\neg a \lor \neg b \lor \neg c) \land (\neg a \lor b \lor c) \land (a \lor \neg b \lor c)$$

For any XOR equation with a length of k, we require exactly $2^{k-1}$ clauses to encode it.

Comment: A XOR equation $x_1\oplus\dots\oplus x_{k+1}=0$, $k\ge3$, is equisatisfiable with $x_1\oplus\dots\oplus x_{k-1}\oplus y=0\land y\oplus x_k\oplus x_{k+1}=0$. Repeating this, and transforming the $3$-XOR equations into $3$-clauses, gives a $3$-CNF with only $4(k-2)$ clauses rather than a $k$-CNF with $2^{k-1}$ clauses.